# Swing JButton not working on actionPerformed method

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have this beginner's project. This time I started from the basics.

Source code: https://github.com/kontext66/GuwiPos/blob/main/GuwiPos

The button is working fine with the lambda approach:
`buttonBasket.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Item Added to Basket!: ");`

But when I try to use `actionPerformed` here to print out the content of the `txtGroup`, it does not show anything.

This is the Button and TextField
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADqVp.png

#### Button:

```
JButton buttonBasket = new JButton();
buttonBasket.setBounds(0,0,300,50);
buttonBasket.setText("Add to Basket");
buttonBasket.setFocusable(false);
buttonBasket.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());   
buttonBasket.addActionListener(this);
```

#### Text Field:

```
JTextField txtGroup = new JTextField();
txtGroup.setBounds(130,35,150,40);
```

#### `actionPerformed`:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e ){
    if(e.getSource()==buttonBasket){            
        System.out.println("Added Item to Basket: "+txtGroup.getText());
    }
```

Comment: You'll also want to take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging through your code, I see that you declare an instance variable `buttonBasket` and then declare a local variable `buttonBasket` in the constructor.  When you call `buttonBasket.addActionListener(this)`, you are really adding the listener to the local `buttonBasket` while the global `buttonBasket` is `null`.

```
public class GuwiPos extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
  
        JButton buttonBasket;
        
         GuwiPos(){
             JButton buttonBasket = new JButton();  // <=== local variable buttonBasket
             buttonBasket.addActionListener(this);
         }
         
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e ){
            if(e.getSource()==buttonBasket){    //<== buttonBasket is null         
               System.out.println("Added Item to Basket: "+txtGroup.getText());
           }
        }
        
}
```

The solution is to change line:

`JButton buttonBasket = new JButton();`

to

`buttonBasket = new JButton();`

Comment: so I tried to remove the `JButton buttonBasket = new JButton();` from the local variable and left the attributes of the button I get this error message 

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JButton.setBounds(int, int, int, int)" because "this.buttonBasket" is null
 at GuwiPos.<init>(GuwiPos.java:79)
 at Main.main(Main.java:24)`

Comment: You still need to create a button.  Instead of ```JButton buttonBasket = new JButton();```, it should be ```buttonBasket = new JButton();```

Comment: It works now I also edited the textField section. thank you sir.